# Vue 3 - number 0 increase (++) is not 1 but 101 in template , why?

Tags: vue.js

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  template: '<div>{{counter++}}</div>'
}).mount('#root')
```

Finally, this code shows 101 on the page. Does someone know the detail about this?

Comment: I'm sure there is a longer explanation to "why" but think of it this way: template can be rendered many many times, so it is a bad idea to use `{{counter++}}` in your template. As for "101" --- who knows, it could be that it rendered 101 times, or that "1"+"0"+"1" occurred. --- instead I suggest you use some other means such as an event tied to a method that increments your counter.

Comment: I'm really surprised you didn't end up with endless loop. **Never** change `data` as side-effect of template rendering....

Comment: @MichalLevý Yeah, you are right. Should never change data as side-effect of template rendering. I just want to know the internal principle of this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The reason your `counter` variable is rendered as 101 and not 1 is because you have a side-effect in your template. When template is rendering the `counter` is incremented, Vue registers the change and trigger rendering again ...it is simply an infinite loop
2. The reason this infinite loop is not so infinite but stops after 101 iterations lies in the fact that Vue internally checks for such situation and [throws an error](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/3ea85c116836d1cf6fb8b7503dc9c269bbf9f113/packages/runtime-core/src/scheduler.ts#L236) (which you should see in browser dev tools console). Condition for throwing an error is `number_of_iterations > RECURSION_LIMIT` where [`RECURSION_LIMIT` is set to 100](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/3ea85c116836d1cf6fb8b7503dc9c269bbf9f113/packages/runtime-core/src/scheduler.ts#L49)

Error:

> Maximum recursive updates exceeded. This means you have a reactive effect that is mutating its own dependencies and thus recursively triggering itself. Possible sources include component template, render function, updated hook or watcher source function.